# How can I get the data of another document in the firebase function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How do I get firestore data in firebase functions?

```
  var number;
  await db.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("info").doc("info").get().then(doc => {
      number = doc.data().get("countUnMutable").toString;
      return db;
  });
```

I want to write the document to a different address using the received value, but it is not written.

```
exports.changeLocation = functions.region('europe-west1').firestore.document('users/{userId}/firstNotes/{noteId}').onCreate(async (snap,context) => {
  const uid = context.params.userId;
  const data = snap.data();
  const noteId = context.params.noteId;
  var number;
  await db.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("info").doc("info").get().then(doc => {
      number = doc.data().get("countUnMutable").toString;
      return db;
  });

  await db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection("notes").doc("firebaseNote:".concat(number)).set(data);

  const alreadyExistedDocument = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('notes').doc(noteId);
  await alreadyExistedDocument.delete();
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're showing now?  Please edit the question to be specific.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added the full code. When I try to move my document, it does not move with a new name.

Comment: What does it do instead?  Are you getting any errors?  Please read about asking a good question, so that your question has everything we need to know to help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does the function gets triggered? If so, what does it return? Check the functions logs. If it doesn't trigger, make sure that the onCreate method is used to properly respond to document creations. For some general guidance on using Cloud Functions with Firestore, refer to [1]. Otherwise, more details about the errors are needed.
[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions